# Retrieve the whole XML response body with Guzzle 6 HTTP Client

Tags: php, xml, http, guzzle

I wanted to use Guzzle 6 to retrieve an xml response from a remote API. This is my code:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => '<my-data-endpoint>',
]);
$response = $client->get('<URI>', [
    'query' => [
        'token' => '<my-token>',
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/xml'
    ]
]);
$body = $response->getBody();
```

Vardumping the `$body` would return a `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream` object:

```
object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)[453] 
private 'stream' => resource(6, stream)
...
...
```

I could then call `$body->read(1024)` to read 1024 bytes from the response (which would read in xml).

However, I'd like to retrieve the whole XML response from my request since I will need to parse it later using the `SimpleXML` extension.

How can I best retrieve the XML response from `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream` object so that it is usable for parsing?

Would the `while` loop the way to go?

```
while($body->read(1024)) {
    ...
}
```

I'd appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [**GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream**](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/Stream.php) implemtents the contract of [*Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface*](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#3-4-psr-http-message-streaminterface) which has the following to offer to you:

```
/** @var $body GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream */
$contents = (string) $body;
```

Casting the object to string will call the underlying `__toString()` method which is part of the interface. The [method name *`__toString()`* is special  in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5172261/367456).

As the implementation within *GuzzleHttp* "missed" to provide access to the actual stream handle, so you can't make use of PHP's stream functions which allows more "stream-lined" (*stream-like*) operations under circumstances,  like `stream_copy_to_stream`, `stream_get_contents` or `file_put_contents`. This might not be obvious on first sight.

Answer (score 7):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', $request_url, [
    'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/xml'],
    'timeout' => 120
])->getBody()->getContents();

$responseXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
if ($responseXml instanceof \SimpleXMLElement)
{
    $key_value = (string)$responseXml->key_name;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I made it this way:

```
public function execute ($url, $method, $headers) {
    $client = new GuzzleHttpConnection();
    $response = $client->execute($url, $method, $headers);

    return $this->parseResponse($response);
}

protected function parseResponse ($response) {
    return new SimpleXMLElement($response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

My application returns content in string with XML prepared content, and Guzzle request sends headers with accept param **application/xml**.

Answer (score 2):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'your URL');
$response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
return $response;
```